# how to remove duplicate function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

java_function.js

```
   $(#call).click(function(){
       alert("gogo");
   });
```

ajax_call.js

```
   This function called when scroll down
    #append  $(#append).append(data);  (data is a.html)
```

a.html

```
<script type=text/javascript src=java_function.js /> 
<script type=text/javascript src=ajax_call.js />

<div id=call>CALL entry</div>
<div id=append></div>
```

scroll down 2-3 times

When I have clicked "CALL entry"

first time show only one alert msg ("gogo")
second time call show 2 alerts msg ("gogo") and ("gogo")

called twice per one click

I want to call alert msg only one time per click
I want to delete duplicate function call (java function)
How to prevent call twice per click?

Comment: Well, when you insert the HTML, you are also inserting the `script` tags again, which means both scripts will be executed and the event handler will be bound again. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve so my only advise would be to use proper DOM manipulation (cloning nodes) instead of using the HTML.

Comment: why you again append the scripts?
`<script type=text/javascript src=java_function.js />`  
`<script type=text/javascript src=ajax_call.js />`

Comment: I hope to show alert msg per click appeded #call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are defining the click event multiple times.

put the click at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#call").click(function(){
    alert("gogo");
  });
});
```

Comment: That will not solve the problem. The `ready` handler will also be executed when the DOM is already ready. Meaning, when you reinsert the `script` tag, the code will be run again.

Comment: I did it. but sometimes it show twice alert.
I think that I have missed "return false" in the java_function()...

Answer (score 0):

In the content you are appending (a.html), does it reference java_function.js ?

If so, then the event may be attached twice.  Remove the reference from a.html

Comment: (#call).function doesn't work when I remove java_function in a.html.(move java_function outside a.html)
It works only one time when it load first.

scroll down 2-3 time 
I got 3 or 4 #call entry.
I hope to work every #call entry(show alert("gogo") per click #call

Answer (score 0):

You could add the html without script lines to avoid duplicate the scripts.

ajax_call.js

```
This function called when scroll down
if (first_scroll){
 $(#append).append(html_full); 
 first_scroll = false;
} else
 $(#append).append(html_lite); //html without script lines
```